# Multiline View containing TextViews and Buttons

Tags: java, android-studio

Can anyone give me clues on where to start looking:
I want to have a multiline View that will take repeated TextViews and Buttons on each line. When the line width is close to full (ie not enough space to take the next View), it starts placing the next Views (maybe TextView or Button) on the following line.
From what I have found: cannot add a View inside a View, at lest in about 2013. Does anyone know if that is still the case

Comment: I would suggest using flexbox-layout. https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout

Comment: I am reading something which may help: https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-create-a-custom-layout-in-android-by-extend